# mysql_real_escape_string on all mySQL queries?

Tags: php, mysql

Is mysql_real_escape_string supposed to replace both addslashes() and stripslashes()??

ie.. do I use it to encode form input variables on MySQL inserts as well as use it in place of stripslashes on MySQL select statements?

Sincerely,
Confused PHP noob

Comment: People are trying to help you.

Comment: thanks, I really want to use mysql_real_escape_string not this PDO thing.

Comment: There is not normally any need to use stripslashes() - or at least, if there is, something is doing something at the wrong "layer".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using the regular [MySQL driver module](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) for PHP, then yes, `mysql_real_escape_string()` is the way to go.  You can ignore `addslashes()` and `stripslashes()` entirely, in fact.

Your query creation will look something like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl (x) VALUES '".mysql_real_escape_string($x)."'";
```

`mysql_real_escape_string()` should be used on any user input that is going into your query.  Note that you don't want to escape your data *any other way* before inserting it.  You shouldn't use `addslashes()` or `htmlentities()`, which are common mistakes when storing HTML fragments in a database.  You should not need to unescape your data in any way after you have retrieved it.

As other posters mention, there are other MySQL database driver modules for PHP, including [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo) and [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/mysqli).  Both offer a feature known as prepared statements, which is an alternative method of creating queries that handles escaping for you.

Comment: Ok, but do I use it when retrieving on SELECT statements as well?

Comment: Yes - generally any data that you put into any query should be escaped, unless you know for sure it's clean.

Comment: money.  All I need to know!  Thanks yall.  I will learn PDO one day.. today is not that day.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statements#Parameterized_statements) instead; see the [PDOStatement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) class.  Prepared statements can be more efficient (if the engine doesn't have to reparse your SQL).  They should also prevent you from accidentally storing escaped data in the db (double-escaping).  Using PDO will make it easier to add support for [other databases](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php).

Comment: I don't want to use PDO, I want to use MySQL only.

Comment: You can use PDO even if you require MySQL-specific features.  You don't *have* to support multiple databases.  It's still a better library than `mysql_connect` and friends.

Comment: @confusedphpnoob That's the wrong attitude to have if you ever hope to become even a decent programmer - let alone a good one.

Comment: @confusedphpnoob - it's a side effect of any question about `mysql_real_escape_string()`.  Invariably, most of the answers in the thread won't address the question, and instead recommend something else.  Don't take it personally  ;)

Comment: Thanks - I just want the answer to the mysql_real_escape_string.  PDO is probably a million times better but I don't care about it right now.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it should do all the backslashing for you (based upon whatever charset the mysql server is)

Comment: no problem. make sure to mark one of the responses as the answer

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should escape strings in preparation for use in MySQL.  However, it is not the be-all, end-all of avoiding SQL injection.  It does in fact leave you very vulnerable to it still.

Better to use the [PHP PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead, parameterized queries are the way to go ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [prepared statements](http://php.net/mysqli). That way you won't have the hassle of manually escaping every query.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT stuff FROM table WHERE something = ?");
$stmt->execute('s', 'something'); // s means string
```

Another option is to use [PDO](http://php.net/PDO), which is an even better version of this, and generally database independent.

Comment: Wrong answer?  Seriously, I DONT WANT THIS PDO NONSENSE.

Comment: @confusedphpnoob  Let me put it to you this way.  There is a fair probability that the mysql_* family of functions will be depreciated in the future.  They are outdated.  They aren't as secure, efficient or well written as the PDO.  The PDO is the "correct" way to handle a database connection in PHP 5 and above.  If you don't want your code to break and stop working in the future, learn to use the PDO.

Comment: Ok thank you.  Sorry for being a dick.  Everywhere I look people answer this question the same way... Just want the answer to this particular question and not a better solution.

Comment: I know the feeling, I've had a similar experience many times on SO.  What I've learned is that, even if the answer I'm getting isn't the one I was looking for it's usually the best answer.  Usually ;)

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

You wouldn't want to use `addslashes()` and `stripslashes()`. If I recall correctly, `mysql_real_escape_string()` is more similiar to `addslashes()`, but it escapes different characters.